# Angular 7 - not getting into callback after GET

Tags: angular

I am just starting getting into Angular 7. I am trying to place a call to an API that resides on another domain. For that I have added all the needed headers to the API's response. Seems like I am not getting CORS error anymore. But I also dont get into results of my call. Here is some relative code:
API:

```js
    getUser() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:98/user/settings/getuser');
    }
```

API call:

```js
    test() {
        this.userService.getUser().pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {
            console.log(users);
        });
    }
```

I am not getting to this code: console.log(users);
The Console shows: ERROR OK

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you try after removing `first()`? Also check the network tab of your browser what it returns?

Comment: A few things. you don't need `.pipe(first())`. it's implied with `http.get()`. Also, you can pass a second callback to `subscribe(users => ..., err => ...)` to catch any errors. Maybe try that and see what you can log. Lastly I would check the network tab to see if your request is going through.

Comment: Yes, I checked Network tab. I see that there are two requests 'getuser' have been placed. Both return the same: An error occurred attempting to identify user accessing this site.
Make sure Windows Authentication is enabled for the site and all
other authentication types are disabled.

Comment: Okay. sounds like it's not Angular issues then, but rather something with your headers or server config. not a windows user so i'm not familiar with this specific error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you only need to subscribe to the method in order to get a response. There's no need to pipe it.

```js
test() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
    (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }, 
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
   });
}
```

This way you'll be able to see whether there's a CORS error or not in the console. Also, it's usually good to have an error handler in RxJS subscriptions, you might want to catch some errors when your codebase gets bigger.